# Why does my public String not change its string?

Tags: java, string, swing, timer

I feel like I saw something similar to this somewhere:
It's where I make `public static String iron = IronCount + " iron";`.
What I feel like I saw was that if my `public int IronCount` changed, the String iron would change, but it doesn't, at least not changing while IronCount is changed in a Timer.
My full code is here (without all of the `g.fillRect()`s):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JComponent;

public class GeneratorAndGraphics extends JComponent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public int IronCount = 0, GoldCount = 0, DiamondCount = 0;
public String iron = IronCount + " iron"; //$NON-NLS-1$

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // vertical lines
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    // iron generator
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(20, 20, 40, 40);
    g.drawLine(20, 30, 60, 30);
    g.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 9)); //$NON-NLS-1$
    g.drawString("Iron Gen", 22, 30); //$NON-NLS-1$
    new java.util.Timer().schedule( 
            new java.util.TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    IronCount++;
                    iron = IronCount + " iron"; // doesn't do anything
                    System.out.println(iron); // doens't print
                }
            }, 
            500
    );
    g.drawString(iron, 25, 45);
}
}
```

I would think that anytime IronCount changed, iron would change, but it doesn't seeing as `g.drawString(iron, 25, 45);` always says: `0 iron` on my JFrame.
Maybe this is an error with Timer, and I would like to have a better alternative to it - such as slowing a for-loop's speed of repeating down.

Comment: Can you include a [mcve] of your code? You probably don't want to be overriding `paint` and you almost certainly don't want to be making a new timer task every time paint is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suggestions:

- Get that timer out of the painting method, it should never be in there. You have no control over that method and it can be called many times
- Create and start the timer once, perhaps in your class's constructor.
- Again, as has been told to you before, painting should be done in the paintComponent method.
- Do call the super's painting method from within your painting method, here `super.paintComponent(g)` within your own painting method.
- In your Timer, you change the state of a field and call `repaint()`
- In the paintComponent method you check the state of the field and change your painting depending on its value.
- Those fields shouldn't be static
- Don't use `java.util.Timer` as this is not Swing thread safe, but rather a Swing Timer, e.g., `javax.swing.Timer`. Google for the tutorial.
- Do post a valid MCVE as has been asked of you countless times. Without your MCVE, we really don't know what else you're doing wrong, or how you're trying to tie it all together.
- Do read the tutorials and avoid guessing as has been recommended many times to you

**THIS** is an MCVE:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Mcve extends JPanel {
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 1000;
    private static final String IRON_FORMAT = "%03d iron";
    private int ironCount = 0;

    public Mcve() {
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, e -> {
            ironCount++;
            repaint();
        }).start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawString(String.format(IRON_FORMAT, ironCount), 25, 45);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mcve");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new Mcve());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: My painting is being done in the paint method, I just took it out since it took up around 100 lines. As for getting the Timer out of the paint method, where  could it go, I'm new to Timers and for loops aren't going to help me.

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2: create and post your [mcve]. Please let's avoid guessing what else you're doing wrong.

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2l: you've edited your question, and **still** haven't posted code we can compile or run, an MCVE. Please see my code above as this is what **you** should be posting, code we can compile run and test.

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2: you've been asked countless times -- it means you haven't read the link that we've been giving you. Again here it is: [mcve]. Please study it. Again, let's avoid frustration and guessing.

Comment: Hah! So with persistent intransigence you could probably be pushed a step further,  where _you_ ask the question for someone, comment on it, edit it up in response to your own comment (perhaps adding a MCVE) and then answer it.

Comment: @pvg: the whole thing frustrated me to a degree where I don't want credit for it. Note that my answer is a community wiki -- no rep from it.

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2: without updates to your code, I can't guess what you may be doing wrong.

Comment: What is "Do call the super's painting method from within your painting method, here `super.paintComponent(g)` within your own painting method" supposed to do?

Comment: @BlazeDaBlur2: it tells the JPanel or JComponent to do its own house-keeping painting, an important thing to do if you're doing animation since this helps get rid of dirty pixels. Again, please look at the [Swing painting tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). The third page of this tutorial touches on this. It also gives you a link to a [much more in-depth tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) that will tell you all about the importance of this.